# Docker support intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, docker

I was running docker inside a VM and was using the Docker integration plugin in IntelliJ (Intellij on my host machine, not vm). I upgraded my OS and now I am able to run my Docker containers directly on my host machine. I can't find how to use the Docker plugin anymore. How can I use the plugin when Docker is running natively? When it was running on a VM, I would go under Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Clouds and would enter MY_VM_IP:2376 under API URL, but now I have no idea what to put there (or even if that's where I configure it). I tried 127.0.0.1:2376 and also tried 192.168.99.100:2376. Both are giving me 'Network is unreachable' error.

Answer (score 2):

I found how:
I edited the /etc/sysconfig/docker file and added "-H 0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock" to OPTIONS. Then I put 127.0.0.1:2376 as API URL under Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Clouds and it's working.